# How do I change default file structure for a new project in Android Studio 3.0.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, project, default, file-structure

I've been trying to setup android studio. All the tutorials online follow a very simple process of installing and making a new project by simply following the prompts. However, whenever I make a new project, my default file structure is different. I'm currently using Android Studio 3.0.1.

This is what I want to create whenever I make a new project.
[image: This is what I want to create whenever I make a new project.]

This is what I actually get.

[image: This is what I actually get.]

In particular, certain folders are missing, such as the manifest folder, and res folder whenever I create a new project.

How can I make the desired structure every time I make a new project?

I'm sure it technically doesn't matter, but I'd like to be able to closely follow tutorials to make it easier to learn. I've been at this for an embarrassingly large amount of time, including several re installations. This has happened to me on two machines, both a windows computer and a mac.

I've tried changing the compact empty middle packages.
Here it is before,
[image: Before]
And after.
[image: After]

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't choose the correct folder for project or you opened an old project, so you still have compile error.

Comment: This is a new project. This issue occurs immediately after a new project is made. My problem is that the folders and files that are automatically made by a new project in my Android Studio are incorrect. Also I'm not worrying about compiling.

Comment: Post a screenshot from the gear's icon menu.

Comment: Just did. I put it the original question because several people have recommended this to me.

Comment: As i said, In your new pics, the class shape not the correct one, so you still have compile error here. check your sdk did you download it correctly? - To be clear extract the package that contain the classes and you will see something like red Exclamation mark

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by compile. I am not compiling anything. The SDK has been downloaded directly using Android Studio. I'm also not sure what you mean by "the package". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Got it! Ibrahim was right. While I never tried to manually compile, the project seems to build itself immediately upon creation. 

After downloading everything I needed for a successful build, the files took the correct form.

For those who are new like me and trying to google this, just try to build and correct all the errors you get. Should just have to download some stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

In the image go to Setting icon and choose `Compact Empty Middle Packages` .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is enabled by default and makes no changes when it is turned off or on!

Comment: Actually, this is correct, assuming that you are able to once successfully. Thanks!